# Cannot see contents of home page <%= yield %> doesn't work

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap, yield, railstutorial.org

I just finished the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I was trying to go back and create something new and very basic using his tutorial as a reference.

After installing bootstrap and importing it into the custom.css.scss, I put a navbar up at the top, similar to the one he adds in the tutorial. When I did this I could no longer see anything written in the home.html.erb file. When I remove the header, I can see it again, why?

My tests say it is there, but my browser (chrome) doesn't show it.

layouts/application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %> </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Basic", 'root_path', id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in",    '#' %></li>         
          <li><%= link_to "New? Sign up",    '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<p>
This is a basic page.  This text should be visible but it isn't.
</p>
```

Comment: You need to run the rb files, are you doing this or just browsing the source code?

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm running the rails server and connecting to it on port 3000 with a browser, just like I did all throughout the tutorial.

Comment: OK, then, problem is somewhere else I guess, what do you see if you do a view source when the pages are blank (when you have the header thing in place)

Comment: Oooh I didn't think of looking there, I do see the text there in the source, oddly enough.

Comment: I tried running my mouse over the page to hi-light everything, sometimes that hi-lights text that's invisible but no such luck.

Comment: I answered my own question, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this was another one of my newbie questions.

The answer was that the text was hidden behind the navbar.  I didn't know how the navbar worked exactly.  I'm new to that bootstrap feature. Apparently you have to set the following in the CSS:

```
body { padding-top: 60px; }
```

Comment: Not "sadly", there was a problem and then you found the solution, that is a happy moment :)